# Core Plot scrolling inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have `UIPageViewController` which present `UIViewController` with Core Plot graphic. Scrolling is not working.

I tried to present `UIViewController` without `UIPageViewController`, scrolling is working.

How to make scrolling working?

PS. Sorry for my english.

Comment: The scrolling is most likely not working because the touch input is going to the `UIViewController` and not the `UIPageViewController`. This is probably happening because the `UIViewController` is covering up the whole space of the `UIPageViewController`. One thing you could try is to put your Core Plot Graphic on a `UIView` instead of a `UIViewController` and add the `UIView` to the `UIPageViewController` as a subview.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for comment, but I really need this UIPageViewController

Comment: You would not be replacing the `UIPageViewController`. You would be replacing the `UIViewController` with a `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

The page view controller captures all of the user interaction events that Core Plot needs to scroll the graph. How is the system supposed to tell when a swipe gesture is intended to scroll the graph and when it is supposed to change pages? I don't think you can have both at the same time.